# Installing MSVC redistributables on Windows 7 embedded standard

Tags: msvcrt, windows-update, windows-7-embedded

I have built a DLL that will be used on a machine running windows 7 embedded standard.
Now that I'm trying to integrate it, it complains about missing `MSVCP140.dll`.

No big deal, I just have to install the redistributables. However, to install the vcredist_x86 package you need to have the universal CRT ([update 2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows))

For some reason, the windows 7 embedded version will not allow the update to be installed.
Without this update, I can't install the redistributables, without which I can't run my project.

Does anyone know how to get the redistributables (2015 or higher) running on windows 7 embedded standard (x86)?

Comment: Your VS version is getting too far ahead of your Win version, troubling.  You can get the files you need from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs, not sure however that every programmer has that.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot! That does seem to work! I'm still looking for a 'cleaner' solution, I guess so that it can be reliably deployed by others, but while I'm developping this will help a ton :)

Comment: Here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9996036f-f7af-412a-98c4-0baf7dbe8009/installing-vc2015-runtime-on-windows-embedded-standard-7?referrer=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9996036f-f7af-412a-98c4-0baf7dbe8009/installing-vc2015-runtime-on-windows-embedded-standard-7?forum=vssetup most bottom comments states that its author somehow managed to install KB2999226 on Windows 7 Embedded x64

Comment: @Renat Thanks, I had found that post as well. Unfortunately, I cannot manually apply the upate as it gives an error message (https://i.imgur.com/olHJ4iX.png) (and yes I am running sp1 as the author of that post :) )

Answer (score 0):

I notice that some programs like OpenJDK come with those DLLs bundled so I came up with this solution that is quite risky but may work: try downloading those missing DLLs and try again. Remember not to mix 32 and 64 bit.

You may also try to manually download the new universal CRT's DLLs before installing MSVC 2015 instead.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/jvdi/12_6/windows/deploy/jvdi_b_deployment-installation-jvdi-windows-12-6.pdf), `MSVCP140.dll` is provided by *Visual Studio C++ 2012 Redistributable Update 4 or later versions*.
So for `MSVCP140.dll` only you might not need (2015 or higher).
Try with that earlier version.

As I understand, VCRedist 2012 is associated with `MSVCR120.dll`, and there is even another version in between (VCredist 2013 with `MSVCR130.dll`), so the linked manual would be in error, even being Cisco... but it is worth checking.

Note: Technically, I am not answering "Does anyone know how to get the redistributables (2015 or higher) running on windows 7 embedded standard (x86)?", but it may give a solution to your problem, and a rephrasing of the question that you really mean to answer.